# Servicestack dynamic datatable

Tags: c#, servicestack

One of the requirement I have is to show some reports(basically queries) as a datatable with sorting & filtering.

Since I have a few queries I was thinking of writing a generic utility which I can use across the board using servicestack ormlite. I was exploring autoquery but it looks like all the poco's should be defined.  In this case we will not have the poco objects defined.

Is there a solution that exists already or we have to build from scratch ?

Answer (score 2):

OrmLite is a code-first ORM but does include some [API support dynamic queries](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27538370/85785). AutoQuery however needs typed Data Models which defines the schema of what can be queried and what to return.

If you don't have the data models for your RDBMS tables already you can initially create them with [ServiceStack.OrmLite.T4 Templates](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite#t4-template-support), which also includes an option to [CreateAutoQueryTypes = true](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite/blob/master/src/T4/OrmLite.Poco.tt#L13) which will also generate AutoQuery Services for each table.

Comment: Thank You, Demis. For now I have used metabase.com for this requirment.